# Using Mocha with TypeScript paths

Tags: typescript, testing, path, compilation, mocha.js

I'm having an issue with running mocha when using the paths + baseUrl configuration in TypeScript

My tsconfig.js is set like so:

```
"baseUrl": "./src/", /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
"paths": {
  "interfaces/*": [
    "interfaces/*"
  ],
  "models/*": [
    "models/*"
  ],
  "schemas/*": [
    "schemas/*"
  ],
  "classes/*": [
    "classes/*"
  ],
  "libs/*": [
    "libs/*"
  ],
  "config/*": [
    "config/*"
  ]
```

and I'm runnings mocha as "mocha build/test"

The compiled TS code fails to find my references since it compiles to

```
var user_1 = require("interfaces/user");
```

and if I add "../" beforehand it will compile without problems

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 22):

You can use `tsconfig-paths`, follow the instructions on [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths#with-mocha-and-ts-node):

```
mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register "test/**/*.ts"
```

Comment: For non-ts-node, the command may just be as simple as `mocha -r tsconfig-paths/register`, since I think `test/**/*.ts` is the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a mocha-TypeScript integration package, such as [ts-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a normal testing integration package (**most popular one**). such as moch-typescript.
With that you only need to setup in test in package.json

```
script: 'mocha --ui mocha-typescript test.ts'
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-typescript

I will give you a better example - test.ts

```
import { suite, test, slow, timeout } from "mocha-typescript";
@suite class Hello {
    @test world() {
        assert.equal(1, 2, "Expected one to equal two.");
    }
}
```

Comment: mocha-typescript is now deprecated, try the package mentioned in Eliran Pe'er's answer

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `ts-mocha`, it's using the `tsconfig-paths` package under the hood to resolve with the tsconfig paths but you have to enable it: `TS_CONFIG_PATHS=true`.

See the official documentation here: https://github.com/piotrwitek/ts-mocha#--programmatic-usage