# Mocha not recognizing path definitions defined in tsconfig in Vue project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, mocha.js

I'm unit testing my pinia stores in a vue project. I use the "@" src reference throughout my project, e.g. "@models" should map to "src/models" as defined in tsconfig compiler options:

```
"paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*",
      ]
    },
```

This works fine when running the code, but breaks with Mocha tests:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@/models'
```

coming from this line:

```
import { Recipe } from "@/models";
```

My relevant directory structure:

```
-project root
/public
/src
   /models
/tests
tsconfig.json
```

My mocha script:

```
"test": "env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' mocha --exit -r ts-node/register 'tests/**/*.ts'"
```

I've tried adding a "path" item to the script TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS and tried all manner of relative paths, but still get the same error.  It's not a huge deal as the tests will run if I don't use the "@" notion for paths, but would like to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you probably want to look for tsconfig-paths. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66964503